# State of Decay: YOSE won’t launch due to DirectX 11 error

Tags: technical-issues, state-of-decay, directx-11, directx, state-of-decay-yose

I bought and installed *State of Decay: Year One Survival Edition* on Steam and then tried to play it, knowing it'd probably give me lag issues out the yang unless I did some serious witchcraft with my settings. Imagine my surprise when it tells me I cannot even open it because I don't have DirectX 11.

I have DirectX 11 installed, and DxDiag says it's running fine on my graphics card. So why is my game insisting it's not there?

Mind you, it gives me the file path for a dump file, but I have no way of opening that file to see if the dump gives more detailed information.

[image: My DxDiag Screen]

Comment: Please add your specifications so we got all needed information so far

Comment: @Nitro.de Does that help any?

Comment: Which graphics card are you using?

Comment: @Nitro.de Mobile Intel 4 Series Chipset, it's a several year old laptop.

Comment: @Nitro.de Intel. It's in the name.

Comment: yeah well but it's a series so there's more than just 1 model.. but however.. i'll answer your question now

Comment: DxDiag reports installed version of DirectX, not the one graphics card uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mobile Intel 4 Series Chipset is a low-end video card, and it was released 3–4 years ago. You can see it [in a benchmark](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/). On the link, the video card got 45–50 points, while an Nvidia 660 TI, e.g., has 4,692 points (just as a comparison).

I don't know if you use Windows 7 or 8 (8.1), but it seems like the Mobile Intel 4 Series [doesn't support OpenGL V.1.2 or higher](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/require-update-for-mobile-intel-4-series-express/96cd8ecf-ae75-4295-99a5-7ea2e27d54f5).

---

Furthermore, your system doesn't fit the system requirements for *State of Decay*, which are:

**Minimum**

- CPU: Core 2 Duo 2.4GHz (E6600) / Athlon 64 x2 3400
- RAM: 2 GB
- Video Card: Video Card:  Radeon HD 2600 XT / GeForce 9600 GSO / Intel HD 3000

**Recommended**

- CPU: Intel Core i5 series or equivalent
- RAM: 2 GB
- Video Card: Radeon HD 4750 / GeForce GT 240 / Intel HD 4000

---

I just found a [very short discussion](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/362313-33-mobile-intel-series-express-chipset-family) about the video card and want to quote it at this point:

> You have a very low end video video chipset, which is rarely up to the task of any kind of gaming. To make matters even worse for you, you have a laptop, so there is no option for simply adding a video card to improve game performance. In this particular case, I'm afraid you are just out of luck.